# Inner join query on Hibernate - SQL queries do not currently support iteration

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and I've this SQL query which works perfectly

```
SELECT count(*) as posti_disponibili from occupazione t inner join
(select id_posto_park, max(date_time) as MaxDate from occupazione 
group by id_posto_park) tm on t.id_posto_park = tm.id_posto_park and
t.date_time = tm.Maxdate and t.isOccupied = 0
```

which gives me all the last items with isOccupied = 0

I was porting it into Hibernate, I've tried to use

```
result = ( (Integer) session.createSQLQuery(query).iterate().next() ).intValue()
```

to return posti_disponibili but i got this exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SQL queries do not currently support iteration
```

How can i solve this? I cannot find the equivalent HQL query

Thank you

Comment: Your query is returning a single value. Why do you want to iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use 
[Query#uniqueResult()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29)

which will give you single result.

```
select count(*) .....
```

will always return you a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate support it's own iterator-like scroll:

```
    String sqlQuery = "select a, b, c from someTable";
    ScrollableResults scroll = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    while (scroll.next()) {
        Object[] row = scroll.get();
        //process row columns
    }
    scroll.close();
```